# fixing a Python progress bar in Command Prompt

Tags: python, performance, optimization, progress-bar, command-prompt

i have wrote the following code (reviewed in code review) in order to print a progress bar in python 2.7 (PS: I know there is a [progressbar module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/progressbar/2.2) in Python)

```
from __future__ import division
import sys

class Progress(object):
    def __init__(self, maxval):
        self._pct = 0
        self.maxval = maxval

    def update(self, value):
        pct = int((value / self.maxval) * 100.0)
        if self._pct != pct:
            self._pct = pct
            self.display()

    def start(self):
        self.update(0)

    def finish(self):
        self.update(self.maxval)

    def display(self):
        sys.stdout.write("|%-100s| %d%%" % ('#' *self._pct, self._pct) + '\n')
        sys.stdout.flush()

# test
import time

toolbar_width = 300
pbar = Progress(toolbar_width)
pbar.start()
for i in xrange(toolbar_width):
    time.sleep(0.1) # do real work here
    pbar.update(i)
pbar.finish()
```

i wish to use this progress bar in my IDE (ex: Pyscripet, PyCharm , etc) and with Command Prompt. When i run with command prompt i have the following two problem that i cannot understand how i can fix.

[image]

1. first, the progress bar prints out the limit (i used 100s)
2. second, the progressbar print all bar one after the other. I wish to
   have only one bar that increase during the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** It may be wrapping due to line length, that terminal looks narrower than 100 characters wide. If you want to assume 80 characters (what most consoles default to), I think you've got 7 characters of other stuff, so use a width of 73 characters for the progress bar.

```
    sys.stdout.write("|%-73s| %3d%%" % ('#' * int(self._pct*.73), self._pct) + '\n')
```

**2.** To stay on the same line, use `sys.stdout.write` and don't include a newline at the end. Then add a `\r` to the beginning of each line to return to the beginning.

```
        sys.stdout.write("\r|%-73s| %3d%%" % ('#' * int(self._pct*.73), self._pct))
```

You can also use `%3d%%` to pad the percentage, so it stays right aligned consistently.

Comment: hey chmulling thanks. I tried your solution but after 10% i have the same problem with command prompt

Comment: Chmulling just change 74 in 73!! :) (but in 100% there is a small imperfection)

Comment: Chmulling with 72 there is a empty space at 100% :P

Answer (score 2):

**problem 1:**

your terminal window is less than 100 characters in width, that's why your progress bar seems to print out of the limit, whereas it is simply wrapping the output at 80 characters (which is the standard and console width on windows).

to avoid wrapping, try:

```
sys.stdout.write("|%-50s| %d%%" % ('#' *int(self._pct/2), self._pct) + '\n')
```

Comment: you could remove "\n" (to avoid printing newline), add "\r" at the beginning (to print at the start), and use `%3d%%` (to maintain the same width).

Comment: that may not work across all possible terminal types. (in fact, no method whatsoever is guaranteed to work across all terminal types). thanks anyway for this useful complement.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem 2**: If you want to display an increasing progression console bar in one line, you have to reset the cursor position, what can be done by writing an *carriage return* sign into the `stdout`.

```
import sys, time

for x in range(10):
    sys.stdout.write((x+1) * '#')
    time.sleep(1)
    sys.stdout.write("\r") # !!! carriage return sign under Windows !!!

print("Fine")
```

But I'm sorry to say: *mostly that won't work in IDE stdout encapsulated environments*

Eclipse, PyCharm, etc. are reading out the stdout pipe and printing changes raw into the console views.

Comment: Thanks Colin, do you suggest to change in "def display(self):" in order to print an increasing progression?

Comment: Mhm, I would check whether there are other 'progression' ways for `console logs` like PyCham, and yeah also even Tail. Maybe starting a GUI-progression bar would help you too. I could imagine to pop-up a simple, not resizeable progression mini-app (wxPython or Tcl/Tkinter).